# ActionCable: is it possible to access connection information at broadcast time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

When receiving messages in ActionCable, we're given access to a connection object and we can get some useful information from it. As an example, this is part of the code I use to construct a log message:

```rb
str = "request_id=\"#{connection.env["action_dispatch.request_id"]}\" fwd=\"#{connection.env["action_dispatch.remote_ip"]}\""
```

But this object is only available in an instance of a Channel subclass. When it comes time to broadcast, we can make a call like this from any web or worker process:

```rb
ActionCable.server.broadcast(channel_name, data)
```

But, when we make the broadcast we don't have access to the channel instance or its helpers.

Is there anything like a 'broadcast hook' in ActionCable, where the channel instance for a given connection can be notified that a broadcast is happening?